# Select by "name" in JSoup

Tags: java, html-parsing, css-selectors, jsoup

I have multiple div's in a webpage URL that I have to parse which have the same class name but different names with no id's.

for eg.

```
<div class="answer" style="display: block;" name="yyy" oldblock="block" jQuery1317140119108="11">
```

and

```
<div class="answer" style="display: block;" name="xxx" oldblock="block" jQuery1317140119108="11">
```

I want to select data and parse from only one of the div's say namely (name="yyy") (the content inside the div's are `<href>` links which differ for each class.

I've looked up the [selector syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) in the Jsoup webpage but can't get a way to work around it. Can you please help me with this or let me know if I'm missing something?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the `[attributename=attributevalue]` selector.

```
Elements xxxDivs = document.select("div.answer[name=xxx]");
// ...

Elements yyyDivs = document.select("div.answer[name=yyy]");
// ...
```

Comment: your previous answer worked great, only after I entered the right syntax I realized there was another div with the same name i.e., there are two div class="answer" style="display: block;" name="xxx" oldblock="block"....is there way I could differentiate between the two of them?

Comment: Look for a different and more unique attribute or content so that you can distinguish them. Or if it's in a fixed order, you could also just get the first one by `.first()` or the second or last one by `.get(1)` or `.last()`.